# I want to run these command in a single run

Tags: unix

```
ssh $1
cd /mk/dist/mktdata
vi /mk/disk/master $2
```

How to resolve this problem so that in a single run all three line get exceuted.

Comment: do you mean to execute the `cd` and `vi` on the remote machine? If so, please update your Q. Good luck.

Comment: yeah, i want to run cd and vi on the remote machine and i have tried running these lines using script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put them in a script or enter `ssh $1;cd /mk/dist/mktdata;vi /mk/disk/master $2`

If you're looking to run them remotely, do the following: `ssh -t $1 "cd /mk/dist/mktdata && vi /mk/disk/master $2"`

Comment: I tried using both but its not working. After entering into remote server i have to manually exceute cd and vi lines.please help.